Creating operations are disabled for entity
I want to call standard Odata V4 service to create warehouse task in S/4HANA on-premise system. I downloaded edmx file from S/4HANA system and generate OData client with cloud sdk library.
The cloud connector and destination is configured properly. Once I deployed my Java application to BTP and test API connection. I got an error message saying "Creating operations are disabled for entity '$SRVD_A2X#API_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TASK_2~A_WAREHOUSEOR'".
I can call this odata service successfully in postman. Is it because creation tag is not turned on in edmx file?
We even changed Updatable and Insertable property values to 'true' (initially it was 'false' in the edmx file) and re-generated vdm files. Still the same error.
Warehouse Order and Task interface
https://api.sap.com/api/OP_WAREHOUSEORDER_0001/path/post_WarehouseOrder__EWMWarehouse___WarehouseOrder___WarehouseTask
Error message
{
  "error" : {
    "code" : "SADL_ENTITY_RUNTIME/011",
    "message" : "Creating operations are disabled for entity '$SRVD_A2X#API_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TASK_2~A_WAREHOUSEOR'",
    "@SAP__common.ExceptionCategory" : "Client_Error",
    "innererror" : {
      "ErrorDetails" : {
        "@SAP__common.Application" : {
          "ComponentId" : "SCM-EWM-API",
          "ServiceRepository" : "SRVD_A2X",
          "ServiceId" : "API_WAREHOUSE_ORDER_TASK_2",
          "ServiceVersion" : "0001"
        },
        "@SAP__common.TransactionId" : "CB2D6B4208500020E006655E7375EEC5",
        "@SAP__common.Timestamp" : "20240529095631.089666",
        "@SAP__common.ErrorResolution" : {
          "Analysis" : "Use ADT feed reader \"SAP Gateway Error Log\" or run transaction /IWFND/ERROR_LOG on SAP Gateway hub system and search for entries with the timestamp above for more details",
          "Note" : "See SAP Note 1797736 for error analysis (
https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/1797736)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


Do you use SAP Cloud SDK for Java or JavaScript? Which version? Can you tell us something about the request payload that works in Postman but not using SAP Cloud SDK?

I am using SAP Cloud SDK for Java. Version is 4.28.0.

SAP Cloud SDK only parses the provided specification file. Depending on the "Updatable and Insertable" flags, it generates type-safe request builder API. It does not create errors for unexpected interactions with the target system.
I see the following options:

Approach service maintainers via documentation or component id SCM-EWM-API, asking what does the error mean. (and/or)
Look at the Apache wire logs. On DEBUG level it writes the full (failing) HTTP request payload of SAP Cloud SDK into our log. You can compare it with the (working) HTTP request payload of Postman. Preferably, with the acquired diff, you can create a new ticket.


check out sap note https://me.sap.com/notes/0003439679 ;
Resolution according to sap:
The functionality of Navigation Property in Resource Path is currently not supported in OData V4.
